# Command to launch a web site in the Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm developing mobile web sites (not web app, so there's no apk, just html, css, and javascript). Is there any command line option or API to launch the Android emulator and passing it the URL of my website so that I can test it in the emulator?

Thanks!

Comment: Er, why not just open the emulator, go to the browser, and navigate to the webpage?

Comment: Hi Mike, I'm trying to hook up my editor to the emulator, so that while i use the editor to develop a site, I can hit Run and it will just launch the site in the emulator.